# How does GLPaint work

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

Ok completely OpenGL-ES noob question. If anyone could explain how apple does GLPaint or better yet the VERY BASIC code of how they accomplished that, I would be thrilled. I am honestly not trying to ask for you to write my program, but trying to understand the basics of how apple accomplished the GLPaint drawing feature.

P.S: I don't need the color conversion, just the drawing (obviously)
Please help

Comment: Hmm, how about Google? http://www.visualnewt.com/OpenGL/learning_iphones_opengl_es/part_i_-_glpaint_dissected_.html

Comment: OK I TRIED THAT SITE BUT DIDN'T UNDERSTAND HOW HE EXPLAINED IT. I did look there I'm not dumb. Next time you try giving comments, be a little nicer, I did say that I was a noob at this stuff

Comment: Also, this site is intended to provide a place where Google searches will land, so saying "just Google it" isn't particularly helpful: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why someone would produce simpler code than [that which already exists](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/GLPaint/index.html) for the Apple GLPaint example, yet does the same thing.  [The analysis](http://www.visualnewt.com/OpenGL/learning_iphones_opengl_es/part_i_-_glpaint_dissected_.html) that Kenny points to is interesting, if a little odd.  I don't know if a line-by-line analysis of this example is the best way to learn what it does.

When working with OpenGL ES on the iPhone, you need to do your drawing in a particular type of Core Animation layer, a CAEAGLLayer, which is hosted inside of a UIView.  The EAGLView class in that example contains boilerplate code for setting up such a layer-hosting view.

The view where the actual drawing is performed is the PaintingView, a subclass of EAGLView.  The PaintingView handles touch events, and incrementally draws a brush texture every so many pixels along the line drawn by your finger.  When the screen needs to be erased, the OpenGL ES context is cleared.

If it's the basic OpenGL ES setup that has you stumped, I'd recommend creating a new project based on the OpenGL ES Application template in Xcode and seeing how that very simple starting application works.