# How to achieve paint brush strokes in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am developing an iOS app that uses a paint brush to draw in a board. I have created a simple paint tool with which user can paint,but what I really need is a paint tool that draws with brush stroke. Is there anyway to achieve the same in native iOS app development?

Here is a sample image of the brush stroke I would like to create:

[image]

Comment: Those are just the plain paths and you can certainly do that with core graphics

Comment: Can you please give me a link or something that does the same?

Comment: @JoeBlow Hi,I am using the same ACEDrawingView(The same one in the link) but it is actually not possessing any paint brush tool with brush strokes.

Answer (score 12):

the fact is you'll have to go to GLPaint

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html

consider also https://github.com/rbuussyghin/glpaint

and https://stackoverflow.com/a/2045262/294884

this is not easy.

Indeed, it's a huge P.I.T.A. Surprisingly, nobody has a ready-made solution for this in iOS.

## For 2019 ...

Surprisingly, as far as I know, there is STILL no ready-made solution for this. Strange thing!

## For 2021 ...

Appears there are finally some libraries in Metal, example

https://github.com/Harley-xk/MaLiang