# How To Create Custom Stroke for Drawing App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In part of my iOS app, I want to allow the user to draw on the screen through touch events. I am familiar with the process of creating a line through touch events. What I want to do, though, is instead of a solid line, have my own custom stroke. For example, something like this: http://artisticpov.jessemaccabe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/brushStrokes_002.jpg .

Is it possible to create my own custom stroke? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: This is not an easy job. Get some idea from these links. http://www.raywenderlich.com/18840/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-advanced-freehand-drawing-techniques--mobile-15602
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487360/how-to-achieve-paint-brush-strokes-in-ios

Comment: Thank you for the references. I will look into them. I knew it wouldn't be an easy task, but hopefully this will give me some ideas. :)